# How to manage python function calls between EC2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two python processes, `process1` and `process2`. They interface in such a way:

```
p1_output = process1_output()
p2_output = process2_output(p1_output)
update_process1(p2_output)
```

`process1` and `process2` have different hardware requirements, leading to a situation where `process1` and `process2` will be run in different EC2 instances.

I was wondering what the best way to handle making function calls between different EC2 instances.

My first guess would be to build a simple Flask app to run `process2`. Then have the output of `process1` packaged into a HTTP request to the `process2` flask app, then wait for the response.

Is there a better way to do this? Are there functions in boto3 that make it easy to send calls between EC2 instances?

Comment: I think the typical API approaches are HTTP or WebSocket, since you need 2-ways communications (request - response). If it is one way, pub-sub/messaging (such as MQTT) works too. So Flask HTTP is definitely acceptable. But whether HTTP is better than WebSocket really depends on a your use case.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to 'loosely couple' the apps via an Amazon SQS queue:

- `process1` would send a message to an Amazon SQS queue
- `process2` would continually poll the queue waiting for a message (use `WaitTimeSeconds = 20` to reduce the number of calls)
- When a message is received, `process2` can process the data contained in the message

The harder part is how to get the 'response' back to `process1`. You could use another queue, but it then becomes difficult to match the response to the original request. If `process1` is waiting for the response and is not sending more messages in the meantime, then it could simply wait for a response in a second queue, then continue processing.

Otherwise, your idea of using an HTTP call to trigger `process2` seems feasible, too. Just make sure the Security Group settings allow the two instances to communicate with each other. Either use two separate Security Groups, or if you are using a single Security Group then configure it to allow access from 'itself'.